# Angular (2 & 4) Access template variable reference from Directive

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a Directive which goal is to add a suggestion list under a prefix-field-text component. This component is basically a searchbar.

My directive currently look like this (in all my code pieces I removed imports to add readibility):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[prefixSuggest]',
    exportAs: 'prefixSuggest',
    host: {
      'class': 'prefix-field-suggest__container'
    }
  })
  export class PrefixFieldSuggestDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    private componentReference: ComponentRef<PrefixFieldSuggestComponent>;

    @Input() fieldTextRef: ElementRef;
    @Input() list: Array<PrefixSuggestLineInterface>;
    @ViewChild('fieldTextRef', {read: ViewContainerRef}) fieldTextContainer;

    constructor(private _injector: Injector, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
        this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PrefixFieldSuggestComponent);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const prefixFieldSuggestFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PrefixFieldSuggestComponent);
        this.componentReference = prefixFieldSuggestFactory.create(this._injector);
        this.componentReference.instance.list = this.list;
        this.fieldTextContainer.insert(this.componentReference.hostView);
    }
  }
```

And my component looks like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'prefix-field-suggest',
  templateUrl: './prefix-field-suggest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prefix-field-suggest.component.scss']
})
export class PrefixFieldSuggestComponent {

    /** Item list to display */
    @Input() list: Array<PrefixSuggestLineInterface>;

    /** Search string typed in search input */
    @Input() searchTerm: string;

    /** Input ID to align itself beneath */
    @Input() inputId: string;

    /** Offset between the suggest and the input; default 0 */
    @Input() offset: number = 0;

    /** Event when an item is selected */
    @Output() itemSelected: EventEmitter<any>;
}
```

The template file for the PrefixFieldSuggestComponent :

```
<div class="prefix-field-suggest" 
    [ngStyle]="{ 'top': offset + 'px'}">
    <span *ngFor="let item of list">
        {{item.title | prefixBoldifyTerm:searchTerm}} {{item.metaData}}
    </span>
</div>
```

the PrefixSuggestLineInterface is just a contract interface so that different people in my team can implement their own suggestion lines, depending on the information they want to display into it. ATM it's basically 2 string fields.

**Question :**
I would like to access to the ViewContainerRef of the prefix-field-ext (searchbar) component, from my directive. I tried many things like #[fieldTextRef], #[fieldTextRef]="mysearchbar", fieldTextRef, etc ....

I tried these possibilities on this simple page :

```
 <div class="prefix-search-group">
          <prefix-field-text prefixSuggest #fieldTextRef="prefixSuggest" list="list" [identifier]="search"></prefix-field-text>
 </div>
```

But in every cases, my fieldTextRef Input is always null. (Because it's not a child element). Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks a lot for your enlightning.

Comment: Where is `prefix-field-text` component? How are `prefix-field-suggest` and `searchBar` related?

Comment: Where is `prefix-field-suggest` in your template?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction on plunker?

Comment: Actually I can't because we use our own libraries and publish it to private NPM registry. But I admit I wasn't clear enough. I'll update subject and answer you : searchbar is in fact prefix-field-suggest. It's a custom component composed of an input and custom style and some parameters.

Comment: You can just recreate the same situation in plunker. I didn't ask to show me all code

Comment: That was the thing ! Thank you very much yurzui, you can post your last comment as answer if you want ! Passing `private fieldTextContainer: ViewContainerRef` as constructor arg did the trick. I could get my container to insert dynamically my component from my directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `ViewContainerRef` for `<prefix-field-text prefixSuggest` just inject it in constructor `prefixSuggest` directive because it is applied on the same element:

```
export class PrefixFieldSuggestDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private fieldTextContainer: ViewContainerRef,...) {}
```